# Binary tree of strings giving me errors Java

Tags: java

I have binary tree that is keeping variables and lines they appear on from a .txt file. I previously had put the creation of new nodes mistakenly in the method to check if its contained, which created an abundance of nodes. At that point it printed the correct information but then exited with an error. I realized this and moved it to the insert method, but now print gives me just an error and no results. I have been struggling with this for awhile now and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

My code for those 2 methods is:

```
public void insert(String inputVar, int line, BinaryNode t)
{
    if (t.var == null)
    {
        t.var = inputVar;
        t.lines[t.count] = line;
        t.count++;
    }
    else if (inputVar.compareTo(t.var) < 0)
    {
        if (t.left == null)
            t.left = new BinaryNode(100);
        insert(inputVar, line, t.left);
    }
    else if (inputVar.compareTo(t.var) > 0)
    {
        if (t.right == null)
            t.right = new BinaryNode(100);
        insert(inputVar, line, t.right);
    }
}
public void printTree(BinaryNode t)
{
    if (t.var == null)
    {   
    }
    else if (t.left == null && t.right !=null)
    {
        System.out.printf("The variable %s appears at lines ", t.var);
        for (int l = 0; l < t.count; l++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ", t.lines[l]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        printTree(t.right);
    }
    else if (t.right == null && t.left != null)
    {
        printTree(t.left);
        System.out.printf("The variable %s appears at lines ", t.var);
        for (int l = 0; l < t.count; l++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ", t.lines[l]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    else
    {
        printTree(t.left);
        System.out.printf("The variable %s appears at lines ", t.var);
        for (int l = 0; l < t.count; l++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ", t.lines[l]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        printTree(t.right);
    }   
}
```

I get an error from the if statement in printTree.

Comment: Please provide the error output.

Comment: Please post the **entire** error message with its trace back.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like if `t.left` and `t.right` are **both** null, you're sailing down to the last `else`, which calls `printTree(t.left)`, and `t.left` is `null`, and `printTree` doesn't behave nicely when its parameter is `null`.

Comment: Using a debugger would probably help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case is `t == null`, but your code doesn't handle that case.  That is, an empty tree is not a node with no variable, but a null node.

Why must your print method be so complicated anyway?

```
public void printTree( BinaryNode t ) {
    if ( null == t )
        return;
    printTree( t.left );
    System.out.printf( "The variable %s appears at lines ", t.var );
    for ( int l = 0; l < t.count; l++ )
        System.out.printf( "%d ", t.lines[ l ] );
    System.out.println();
    printTree( t.right );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may reach the last case (`else` in printTree() ) when both `t.right == null && t.left == null` so you make a recursive call with both (null) childs  and then fall on a NPE in the first check
 `if(t.var == null)` where `t` is null